# Rotating table problem and problem solving methodology

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

Here is the question 'A  table with smooth horizontal surface is turning at an angular speed ω about its axis. A groove is made on the surface along the radius and a particle is gently placed at a distance 'a' from the center. Find the speed of the particle as its distance from the center becomes L.'

[image]
I have attached my version of approach and the solution. What I did was to write v/x (where v is velocity of particle at x distance from center) instead of ω in the integral. I'm not able to find out what was wrong in it. Treating ω as a constant was of course a great idea but I should've got same results if my method was correct. Where am I missing it?
[image: My version]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but you are mixing *radial velocity* with *tangential velocity*.

Specifically, in your fourth equation, $V$ on the right hand side is *radial-velocity* while $V$ on the left hand side is *tangential velocity*.

The book is focusing on radial velocity by adopting the rotating coordinate system.